# Switching to new window with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, new-window

I have a list with all `xpath` of links

Here is my code:

```
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
for stat in stats:
  
     
     
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, stat))).click()
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
     for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            print(driver.current_url)
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(original_window)
            print(driver.current_url)
            break
            
     time.sleep(15)
```

It works the first time but after that it gives me this error:

```
https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/fr/1/season/81152/headtohead/322375/90970/match/27122060
https://www.bountou1x2.com/sport.jsp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Hama\Documents\Python project\test3.py", line 45, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, stat))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Hama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Here is how Stats is defined:

```
stats = []

for a in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
   aa = a.get_attribute("idavv")
   if aa is not None:
      aaa = "//*[@id=\"simple-row-box-prematch-" + aa + "\"]/td[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"
     
      stats.append(aaa)
```

if i let only the click event the code works fine like this and opens all windows:

```
for stat in stats:
  
     
     
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, stat))).click()
     
     time.sleep(15)
```

The error appears only when i try to switch from the old to new and from the new to old window, it works only the first time

I print the current url just to see if it's switching as it most

Help is appreciated, thanks to all of you

Comment: All I can tell so far, and you probably already know, is that `stat` is not found to be clickable and times out after 10 seconds. Can you include how you have defined `stats`? Also the HTML of the page you are testing please?

Comment: @C.Peck I added how stats is defined the url of the original page is [link](https://www.bountou1x2.com/sport.jsp), and if i just loop to only click, it clicks fine all links, the problem appears when i swith to the new window

Comment: First of all, this line confuses me. `aa = a.get_attribute("idavv")` -- you are trying to get the value of an attribute called `idavv`? I can't find that attribute anywhere on the page. I also can't find any element with an ID like `simple-row-box-prematch`. Can you help me figure out exactly which elements you are trying to locate?

Comment: When you open there is a button called TODAY, it's on the left side of the page, when you click that button you will get the list of links

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem, it was the frame, it works the first time because the frame was selected, everytime i switch back i must swith to the frame too so my code become:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, stat))).click()
 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
 for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
    if window_handle != original_window:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        print(driver.current_url)
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(original_window)
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("receiver"))
        
        break
```